# Tamanho de uma String Java + Hibernate

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, hibernate

Existe alguma maneira de persistir uma string sem limite de tamanho para o banco utilizando o hibernate?

Se eu mapear minha classe e não limitar o campo, o hibernate automaticamente cria um limite de 255 caracteres.Eu poderia dar um limite maior, mas o ideal seria que o campo não tivesse limites.

Alguém ai sabe como me ajudar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O tamanho padrão de campos de texto é de 255 caracteres, mas você pode mudar para mais, assim como para menos.

Uma forma de fazer isso é usando a anotação [`@Column`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) do JPA, especificando o atributo `length`. Exemplo:

```
@Column(name="DESC", nullable=false, length=512)
private String description;
```

Porém, campos de texto sempre terão um limite, mas não do Hibernate e sim do próprio banco de dados.

Alguns bancos de dados limitam campos do tipo `VARCHAR` em 255, outros em 2000 ou 4000 caracteres.

Para armazenar texto maiores, alguns bancos dão suporte a tipos como `TEXT` ou `CLOB`. Nestes casos, você pode usar a anotação `@Lob` do JPA. Exemplo:

```
@Lob @Basic(fetch=LAZY)
@Column(name="REPORT")
private String report;
```

Observação: a anotação `@Basic(fetch=LAZY)` serve que esse campo seja lido do banco somente quando o método `getDescription()` for chamado. Isso evita leitura desnecessária de grandes quantidades de dados.

Comment: Obrigado @utluiz, esclareceu todas as minha dúvidas!